# groupby object in pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem using groupby object in pandas.

For example, if I have a DataFrame named df, and I select a group in df.grouby('column'), when I try group.column[0] or group['column'][0], it doesn't work.

How can I Solve this problem ?

Comment: a `groupby` object is just metadata describing how to perform the `group`ing, it doesn't return a `Series` or `DataFrame` until you perform some kind of aggregation on it, e.g. `group.sum()`

Comment: yes but if you select a group inside de groupby object, it's a DataFrame. But I don't understand why it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I just figured the problem, the index doesn't start at 0 but at the original position in the DataFrame. How do I set it to 0 again ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to reset the index of the filtered dataframe.

```
for name, subdf in df.groupby("column"):
    subdf = subdf.reset_index() 
    print (subdf["column"][0])
```